# Find and install missing X11 font based XLFD data

Tags: x11, fonts, x-server

I need to migrate from one Windows X-Server product (X2Go) to an other (MobaXterm). I have a Unix application that works nicely under the old X-Server, but complains about missing fonts on the new X-Server. I tried to manually copy my fonts from one X-Server to the other (copy files, then xset fp+ path then rehash etc. ...), some fonts were taken over (fewer missing fonts messages), but some are still missing. The missing fonts are given in XLFD format e.g.:

```
XLoadQueryFont for "-b&h-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-normal-sans-12-*-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1" failed.
```

I would like to find out which files contain the missing fonts, and how to migrate them to the new X-Server.
I already grep-ped through my font files and fonts.dir file for the XLFD font names, but no luck.

Comment: Do these X servers use `fontconfig`?  If they do, you probably want to look for `fontconfig`, err, config files.

Comment: I can issue the fc-list command in both cases, and the results are identical, no difference, but the application misses a couple of fonts in case of the MobaXterm X-Server, and runs without problems in case of X2Go.

Answer (score 1):

Grepping my `/usr/share/fonts/X11/*/fonts.dir` finds e.g.

```
lutRS12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz -b&h-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-normal-sans-12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1
```

and

```
$ dpkg -S lutRS12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
xfonts-75dpi: /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/lutRS12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
xfonts-100dpi: /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/lutRS12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
```

finds that these are in the `xfonts` packages on Debian (and probably on Debian derivatives as well).

I've no idea how to obtain them for MobaXterm, but I suppose you can extract them from the Debian packages, if you don't find them directly.

If there are not in some kind of package on your system, I suppose you'll have to update `fonts.dir` manually, restart everything etc.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, thanks, but the lucida... was just an example, I already installed it. I have other perhaps proprietary fonts, that are still missing e.g. "-linotype-helvetica-medium-r-normal--18-*-*-*-p-*-iso8859-1". I can't even find on the old X-Server from which file are they coming from.

Comment: "Linotype" sounds very proprietary, and it's e.g. not on my system. If the fontnames are not configurable somewhere in your application (via X resources), I *think* you can use `fonts.alias` to substitute other Helvetica fonts etc., but I've never tried that myself.